# How to find a cursor's records count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this is my cursor

```
 declare @product1 CURSOR 

 SET @product1 = CURSOR for SELECT Id from Tbl_StkDetailedBookStock where IsActive='True'         
 and  BookStockId=@tempd4 ;
```

here I have 2 records in cursor (

```
SELECT Id 
from Tbl_StkDetailedBookStock 
where IsActive = 'True' and BookStockId = 11
```

So how to find cursor count = 2 because I want find the cursor count and do some operation based on that count.

anybody help to find this.

thanks.

Comment: You can't find that information, unless you enumerate the entire cursor, e.g. you just fetch the next row until there is no more row to be fetched.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT @@CURSOR_ROWS AS TotalRows` will gives you total number of rows in a cursor. But for that you need a static cursor. For non static cursor you need to count your self by iterating cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a calculated column to return the row count along with other data (it would be the same value in every row):

```
SET @product1 = CURSOR FOR
  SELECT Id, COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
  FROM Tbl_StkDetailedBookStock
  WHERE IsActive='True'
    AND BookStockId=@tempd4
;
```